# L'interiezione "per la miseria" è ritenuta volgare o offensiva?

Tags: interjections

Ho trovato una quantità di traduzioni inglesi dell'interiezione "per la miseria" e variano dall'innocuo "good grief" a cose che non direi nella buona società e perfino ad espressioni che, per essere troppo grossolane o offensive, non direi mai.

Mi potreste spiegare quale "livello di volgarità" si associa a questa interiezione?

Comment: È così poco volgare che ormai si usa quasi solo scherzosamente: nove italiani su dieci, se sono veramente in collera, diranno ben altro.

Comment: Se vuoi essere più formale, usa
> Perbacco
.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nonostante non sia considerabile volgare o offensivo rimane un'esclamazione di rabbia, quindi da evitare in determinate situazioni formali più perché in determinati contesti devi mantenere un certo contegno che per un vero problema con questa imprecazione. In contesti informali è tranquillamente utilizzabile per esprimere appunto rabbia o indignazione senza risultare eccessivamente volgare.